# Link static/css file with Django template

Tags: python, html, css, django

I am pretty new to Django and I am trying to link CSS file with my HTML document and I have tried using all possible ways posted on StackOverflow and I am unable to locate what is the issue here.

Here is the directory and file structure:

[image: Here is the directory and file structure:]

settings.py

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, '/')
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static"),
)
```

index.html

```
{% load static %}
<link rel="stylesheet" type="css/text" href="{% static 'css/style.css' % }">
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ops. Silly mistake. It was all about indentation and minor `type` tag changes. Here is what worked out for me.

```
{% load static %}
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'css/style.css' %}">
```